# Multi Label Classification - Incorrect training hyperparameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I am working on a multi-label image classification problem, using `TensorFlow`, `Keras` and `Python 3.9`.

I have built a dataset containing one `.csv` file with image names and their respective one-hot encoded labels, like so:

[image: Dataset Sample]

I also have an image folder with the associated image files. There are around 17,000 images, and each one can be classified with a total of 29 possible labels. The dataset is fairly well balanced. These labels refer to the visual components found in an image, for example, the following image belongs to classes `[02, 23, 05]`.

[image: Image Sample]

- 2 - Human Beings
- 5 - Plants
- 23 - Arms, Armour

This method of image labelling is popular in Trademark Imaging and is known as [Vienna Classification](https://nivilo.wipo.int/vienna/index.htm).
Now, my goal is to perform predictions on similar images. For this, I am fine-tuning a `VGG19` network with a custom prediction layer defined as follows:

```
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(29, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)`
```

All images are properly resized to `(224, 224, 3)` and their RGB values scaled to `[0, 1]`. My network summary looks like this:

```
Model: "model_5"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_11 (InputLayer)       [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 tf.__operators__.getitem_1   (None, 224, 224, 3)      0         
 (SlicingOpLambda)                                               
                                                                 
 tf.nn.bias_add_1 (TFOpLambd  (None, 224, 224, 3)      0         
 a)                                                              
                                                                 
 vgg19 (Functional)          (None, 7, 7, 512)         20024384  
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d_3   (None, 512)              0         
 (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                        
                                                                 
 dense_12 (Dense)            (None, 29)                14877     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 20,039,261
Trainable params: 14,877
Non-trainable params: 20,024,384
_________________________________________________________________
```

The problem I am facing is in regard to the actual training of the network. I am using `Adam` and the `binary_crossentropy` loss function which I believe is adequate for multi-label problems. However, after around 5 hours of training, I am fairly dissapointed with the accuracy it's achieving.

```
Epoch 10/10
239/239 [==============================] - 1480s 6s/step - loss: 0.1670 - accuracy: 0.1969 - val_loss: 0.1656 - val_accuracy: 0.1922
```

I am somewhat familiar with multi-class classification but this is my first attempt at solving a multi-label problem. Am I failing at any point before training, is `VGG19` not ideal for this task, did I get my parameters wrong?

Comment: Is this a multilabel singleclass classification problem? Singleclass means that you only consider whether there are for instance humans in the picture, but it is not relevant how many.

Comment: Yes, it does not matter how many of a specific visual element there is. One is enough to assign a specific label to the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multilabel problems are different in evaluation. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75448156/12858691). Low accuracy could mean nothing. Consider that a prediction for one sample is only correct if the entire vector of 29 elements is correct. This is hard to achieve. For your example that is:

```
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0...,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I recommend you to use the binary accuracy, f1-score hamming loss or coverage to evaluate your model, depending on what aspect of the prediction is most important in your context.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up defining a function for Hamming Loss and using it in my metrics alongside binary accuracy! Much better results this way.

Comment: I would recommend not using hamming loss, but check the example based and label based F-Scores. Also, maybe coverage, depending on how sparse your label space is.

Comment: @phoxis what are label based F-scores? Thanks for the comment, I updated the answer.